# conflicting attributes error in Spark dataframe except

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql, except

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2 built after joining some tables that are partitioned on id, month and year. These two dataframes have different data due to the filters on date ranges used in the joins.

```
grpDf1 = df1.groupBy(df1("id"), df1("orderId"), df1("userid"), df1("name"))
             .agg(min(df1("dateId")).as("dateId"), min(df1("month")).as("month"), min(df1("year")).as("year"),sum("quantity").as("quantity"),sum("amount").as("amount"))

grpDf2 = df2.groupBy(df1("id"), df2("orderId"), df2("userid"), df2("name"))
             .agg(min(df2("dateId")).as("dateId"), min(df2("month")).as("month"), min(df2("year")).as("year"),sum("quantity").as("quantity"),sum("amount").as("amount"))
```

When I try to do `grpDf2.except(grpDf1)`
I get an error Conflicting attributes: id#8,orderId#5,userid#6,name#7

But when i do union of `grpDf2.union(grpDf1)`, there is no error.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Is it exact code u used? Are you expecting to define grpDf2 grouping by fields of df2? I see df**1**("id") in it.
Still it should not cause any issue.

What is the actual error?

What are outputs of:

```
df1.printSchema

df2.printSchema
```